# A glob pattern to to match anything(file or folder) except one folder

Tags: glob

I have this glob pattern and been trying to exclude the `i18n` folder from it:

```
dist/assets/!(i18n)/**
```

Basically, I want to match everything inside the `assets` folder except the `i18n` folder.
The `i18n` folder contains a few `.json` files.

Answer (score 0):

This worked eventually:

```
dist/assets/**/!(ar.json|en.json)
```